# Find, copy & consolidate, copy to other server

Tags: python, awk, grep, text-files, sh

I need help in extracting the .gz files from different folders and consolidate to one folder and later move to another server, and also create a output file as to what has copied from where to where

```
#!/bin/sh

PATH="/home/john"
OUTPUT="/tmp"

while read note1
do
zgrep -il `echo $messages.txt|awk '{print$1}'` PATH`echo $trademessages.txt|awk 'print$2'` >> OUTPUT
done < trademessages.txt;
```

messages.txt contains below .

```
0060700       2015/03/03/     Tue, 03 Mar 2015
0125314       2015/03/03/     Tue, 03 Mar 2015
0125314       2015/12/22/     Tue, 22 Dec 2015
0125314       2015/12/22/     Tue, 22 Dec 2015
0417894       2015/06/25/     Thu, 25 Jun 2015
0417902       2015/06/25/     Thu, 25 Jun 2015
```

Comment: ...do you have a question? I'd recommend learning [ask].

Comment: Thanks for that khelwood , But since this is my first post I didnt know how to ask , I will go thru the link that you provided me